# Inter-process communication stream between two different programs

Tags: c++, ruby, linux, inter-process-communicat

I'm looking for a specific kind of inter-process communication, but I don't know what it's name is. I'm looking at a producer consumer relationship. The producer should write to a container. The container should only have enough space for one message. When the producer writes a new message, the old message gets dropped. In other words, the producer should only block if the consumer process wants to read from that container.

This description doesn't match any other pattern I know of (pipes, sockets {I'm thinking UDP might be overkill?} and shared memory is out of the question {I think because I don't know how to share a memory address between C++ and Ruby}) At this point, I'm thinking I'm just going to write a text file and lock that, which I've done before, but is there a faster way of accomplishing this? Is it a mis-conception that this method would be slow?

I am trying to communicate between `c++` and `ruby`, but I consider this question to be language agnostic.

Comment: ØMQ should be able to do the job quite easily.

Comment: The Ruby driver is not really functional with the most recent version right now, but if you could give me an example with `c++` or any other language I would still accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: Why is shared memory out of the question?  It seems like the easiest in this instance.You can't recall data from any of the pipes (pipes, fifos, sockets).  With MQs the producer will need to read (to delete old msg) before replacing the data.  SharedMem with a lock seems like what you want - the producer just keeps overwriting the same area and the consumer reads whenever the consumer wants to read.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible or simple to share the virtual memory address between the two programs. I only know how to do that with forking.

Comment: Forking won't share a process' normal heap & stack, etc., memory with children - they get their own copy.  But shared memory segments do get shared after the fork.  Take a look at http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/posix-semaphore-example-using-fork-and-shared-memory-330419.html and similar.

Comment: I understand forking, I just don't think it's possible to fork a Ruby based process from a C++ process.